# Python: Code analysis shows multiple undefined errors in OOP

Tags: python, oop, methods, spyder

I've defined a new class called Email, and had to create a few methods. The problem is, I define the variables in the constructor, and the code analysis on Spyder keeps saying that `inbox`, `is_spam` and `has_been_read` aren't defined in some of my methods, even though I defined it in the constructor.

I have searched everywhere, but I really can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

I am using Spyder 4.1.5 and Python 3.8

My code is as below:

```
class Email(object):
    
    def __init__(self, has_been_read, email_contents, is_spam, from_address, inbox):
        assert type(has_been_read) == bool and type(is_spam) == bool
        self.has_been_read = has_been_read
        self.email_contents = email_contents
        self.is_spam = is_spam
        self.from_address = from_address
        self.__inbox = []
        
    def mark_as_read(self):
        # Creating method to change has_been_read boolean to True
        return self.has_been_read == True
    
    def mark_as_spam(self):
        # Creating method to change is_spam to True
        return self.is_spam == True
    
    def add_email(self, eamil_contents, from_address):
        return Email(False, email_contents, False, from_address)
        inbox.append(Email)
        
    def get_count(self):
        print(len.inbox)
        
    def get_email(self, i):
        print(inbox[i].email_contents)
        return inbox[i].mark_as_read
    
    def get_unread_emails(self):
        for i in inbox:
            if has_been_read == False:
                print(i) 
                
    def get_spam_emails(self):
        for i in inbox:
            if is_spam == True:
                print(i)
                
    def delete(self, i):
        del self.inbox[i]
```

Comment: You are forgetting to access them with `self`. `self.__inbox`, `self.is_spam` etc.

Comment: One problem is that you shouldn't use two "=" signs in the return statements as this: `return self.has_been_read == True`

Comment: As a side note, are you sure that you want to use [name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-single-and-double-underscore-before-an-object-name) by using a name starting with a double underscore for `__inbox`?

Comment: @go2nirvana Thanks, that worked! I don't know how I missed that

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I wasn't even aware of that, so thanks for the heads up, I removed the two underscores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note how every instance method's first argument is `self`. This is a reference to the class instance. So if you want to access the field `inbox` from one of those methods, you need to refer to the instance, `self`. for example

```
def get_count(self):
    print(len(self.inbox))
```

if you don't, you're telling the python interpreter to find the local variable `inbox` which is not defined, even though `self.inbox` is.

obviously, this is the same thing @go2nirvana pointed out.